# how do you build gstreamer's gst-launch pipelines?

Tags: linux, audio, video, gstreamer, openmax

Let's say you have a video file.
As far as I searched, you first need to know what container it uses by `mediainfo` command.

```sh
$ mediainfo your_path_to_a_video.file
```

you then need to find a demuxer for the container, so you do

```sh
$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep your_container_name_such_as_ogg
```

now that you have a proper demuxer, such as `oggdemux`, you can split video and audio.  If you want to display the video, you first need to know the codec name, and you will need to decode it to output to the screen.
Going back to the `mediainfo` output, you go find the video `Format`, and you do

```sh
$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep format_name_such_as_theora
```

You will find `theoradec` and you check its details by

```sh
$ gst-inspect-1.0 | decoder_name_such_as_theoradec
```

to see the `sink` and `src`.  You now find the `src` is `video/x-raw` so you will need to find the final sink to output the video on display, such as `xvimagesink`.

I am just writing this all based on a [web page in Japanese](http://www.clear-code.com/blog/2014/7/22.html), and I didn't find any other pages that **explained more than this** (either in English or Japanese).

I want to find pages explaining how one can complete a pipeline based on mediainfo and so on.  Even after I read the web page, I am still not sure how to match capabilities between elements to elements.

How do you build your pipelines?
How do you match caps?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to playback your video file, you can do:

gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/your/video

If you need to decode it to a raw video format and do further processing, you can :

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///path/to/your/video ! video/x-raw ! further_processing
```

Same goes with audio, and you can even name your uridecodebin to separate audio and video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///path/to/your/video name=d ! video/x-raw ! further_video_processing d. ! audio/x-raw ! further_audio_processing
```

If you want to see what the actual pipeline looks like, you can set the GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR environment variable to dump a dot representation:

```
GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=$PWD gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/your/video
```

Then:

```
dot -Tsvg name_of_the_dot_file.dot -o mypipeline.svg
```

Edit : as for the documents I read to figure this out, the "application development manual", the manual page for gst-launch and gst-inspect along with the various docs here : http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/docs should get you started.

Comment: the main point of this question is how you understood how to build piplines.  Which document did you read to know how the things can be constructed?