# Gstreamer / RTSP - Creating a pipeline to reduce latency due to rtpjitterbuffer

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, pipeline, rtsp, rtp

I am accessing a `RTSP` video stream from a VIRB 360 camera. I am able to play the stream using the following `gstreamer` command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1
```

However, there is a **3 second delay** in the streaming, which needs to be eliminated. The output of the above command (due to `-v`) has been uploaded [here](https://technicalproductsinc-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/syamprasad_rajagopalan_technicalproductsinc_us/Ed9JT4vTEmNAmcp7gq44lhYBzLrMG3kvUijoOwwThpQuOw?e=YmOgvc). I also created a few `.svg` files for the pipeline following the method described in this [question/ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496901/how-do-you-build-gstreamers-gst-launch-pipelines). Those files has been uploaded [here](https://technicalproductsinc-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/syamprasad_rajagopalan_technicalproductsinc_us/EsRaaOuuzghAppnBLE6N-FgBzAlv8eCV4tY8e_NNx19sYQ?e=iWZYL2). I believe `mypipeline4.svg` and `mypipeline5.svg` represent the complete pipeline (Multiple `dot` files were generated by a single pipeline and that's reason for multiple `.svg` file). In the `.svg` files, can see a `latency=2000` under `rtpjitterbuffer`.

The plan is to build the same pipeline by adding components manually instead of using `playbin`, and then set latency property for `rtpjitterbuffer`. I have tried the following commands:

1) `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1 ! udpsrc ! rtpsession ! rtpssrcdemux ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpptdemux ! queue ! udpsink ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! playsink`

2) `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1 ! udpsrc ! rtpsession ! rtpssrcdemux ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpptdemux ! queue ! udpsink ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvoverlaysink`

However, in both cases, I received an error: `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link udpsink0 to queue1.` How can I fix this? Also, from my experiments I pretty sure that the rest of the pipeline also has errors. How can I optimize this pipeline?

Comment: Instead of rebuilding from scratch - how about connecting the `deep-element-added` signal from the pipeline aka `GstBin`? Whenever an element gets added by `playbin/rtpbin` you should get the signal called with that element. If its an `rtpjitterbuffer` you can set your desired properties.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch I am relatively new to gstreamer and didn't quite understand your comment. I did try adding `latency=0` and `latency=10000` at the end of my `playbin` command. But in both these cases, the verbose output showed a latency of 2000.

Comment: Well you would have to write a real GStreamer application. `gst-launch-1.0` is quick start but quickly comes to its limits.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch okay. I will follow the tutorial and see how that goes.

Comment: Its a complex framework.. with some learning curve. There are a lot of things to read and learn. So maybe first make things work. Fine tuning can be done anytime..

Comment: you can try to set the latency using the following: gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1  uridecodebin0::source::latency=0

Comment: @PrabhakarLad I had already tried something similar. I also tried your exact command. But in both cases, the video is very choppy. I was able to obtain better results using `ffplay`. So, now I am trying to get it into `OpenCV` using ffmpeg. `OpenCV` / C/ C++ is the ultimate destination.

Answer (score 5):

First, you are not supposed to connect anything to a sink in GStreamer. The sink is the end of the line and should just receive data. Especially the **udpsink is to send UDP packets to the network**. See more at documentation:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/udp/udpsink.html?gi-language=c

I am also trying to reduce my latency, and the best that I got until now is:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.20.0.188:554 latency=0 buffer-mode=auto ! decodebin ! vaapisink sync=false`

I'm getting 400ms delay through it while in the camera app I have 150ms, I wanna to reduce it.

I hope this helps you ;)